# How to update route on clicking angular material dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing

I have a home page in which I want to display a login dialog when clicking on the login button. The dialog works fine but the URL doesn't change and it stays the same 'localhost:4200/home'. I want that in addition to opening the login dialog on the home page, the URL also changes to 'localhost:4200/home/login'

**homeComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators, Form } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LoginComponent } from '../authentification/login/login.component';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})



export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,private router: Router) { }


   login(){
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.height='270px';
    dialogConfig.width='1200px';
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = false;

     this.dialog.open(LoginComponent,dialogConfig);
   }

  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are opening material dialog in the same component `home.component.ts`
Easy way to achieve this.

1. create a new component if you are using angular CLI run this command

   ng g c login-dialog

then copy your login dialog code from the homepage and paste  in `login-dialog.component.ts`

2. update your routes
   go into `app-routing.module.ts` and update routes e.g

   {path : '/home/login', component : LoginDialogComponent}
3. add router link under the button click e.g

   <a [routerLink]="['/home/login']">Login

now when you click on the Login button it will open dialog from newly generated component and the route will be updated with this route `'localhost:4200/home/login'`